# How to qdel range of jobs?

Tags: sungridengine

I want to `qdel` a range of jobs, with consecutive IDs. For example:

```
qdel 18280 18281 18282 18283 18284 18285
```

Imagine I had a longer list of consecutive IDs like this. I obviously don't want to have to type them all by hand. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the expansion `{18280..18285}` as the argument of `qdel`:

```
qdel {18280..18285}
```

Comment: Nice! I was always doing ``for i in `seq 18280 18285`; do qdel $i; done`` :S